# Sharepoint Extenal List and Custom Field Types

Tags: sharepoint, external, custom-fields

I have an odd issue.

I have client that wants a sharepoint list what is populated from a WCFService. That part is working quite well.

I have a bdcmodel that is mapping the WCF data and I can create an external list from the bdcmodel as well so that is working fine.

The issue I have is that one of the properties in the model is actually a collection of entities called Attributes. The objects in this collection simply have 2 properties Name and Value so really they are just a key value pair.

The client wants to see the list of attributes of the parent entity in the external list. So there would be an Attributes column and within that column would be the list of attributes for each parent object.

Is there even a way to do this? I am looking into Custom Field Types, but it seems like these are really intended to be singular values.

How would I create a list within and external list?

Any help anyone can give would be great even if its just to tell me that there really isn't a stable way to do this so I can go back to the client and tell them we will need to build a custom list to support this because the OOB external list and custom fields and custom field types won't support this kind of nested listing.

Comment: I decided to serialize my collection to JSON and make the field a string. Then I am going to set up my FieldRenderingControl to tile out the objects the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to set up the custom field as a string and when I get my collection in from the BdcModel I am serializing it to JSON and then passing it to the field. When the field is viewed in display, edit or new I have overridden the FieldRenderingControl and I am tiling the collection out that way.